# Changes the <li> tag list structure if it finds a specific character in the link name

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

I have a list code

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="https://"> Home </a></li>
     <li><a href="https://"> Profile </a></li>
     <li><a href="https://"> _Vision </a></li>
     <li><a href="https://"> _Mission </a></li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

If there is a character in the link name **"_"** (without the quotes) then the structure of the code list will be a sub-menu, and enter the tag list has previously has-sub class.

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="https://"> Home </a> </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="https://"> Profile </a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="https://"> Vision </a></li>
         <li><a href="https://"> Mission </a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

how the javascript code to be able to execute it, because I am still in the learning stage uses javascript code or jQuery.
I am very grateful for his help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrap function that will simply wrap an `li` tag with a `ul.sub-menu` tag if its text begins with `_`

```js
function wrap(node) {
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.className = "sub-menu";
  node.textContent = node.textContent.trim().substr(1, node.textContent.length);
  node.parentNode.insertBefore(ul, node);
  let inserted = node.previousElementSibling.appendChild(node);
  $(inserted).parent().prev("li").addClass("has-sub");
}

$("ul > li > a").each((index, ele) => {
  if (ele.textContent.trim().charAt(0) === "_") {
    wrap(ele.parentNode);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="https://"> Profile </a></li>
    <li><a href="https://"> _Vision </a></li>
    <li><a href="https://"> _Mission </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that's great, and is it possible to remove the "_" in the link name?

Comment: @ATLM adjusted.

Comment: Thank you @zfrish

Answer (score 0):

```js
let submenu = null
Array.from(document.getElementById('nav').children[0].children)
    .map(
        function(e) {
            if (e.children[0].textContent.charAt(0) == '_') {
                if (!submenu) {
                    submenu = document.createElement('ul')
                }
                e.children[0].textContent = e.children[0].textContent.substring(1)
                submenu.appendChild(e)
            } else {
                if (submenu) {
                    e.previousSibling.replaceWith(submenu)
                    submenu = null
                }
            }
        }
    )

if (submenu) {
    document.getElementById('nav').children[0].lastChild.replaceWith(submenu)
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="https://">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://">Profile</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://">_Vision</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://">_Mission</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://">Menu2</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://">_sub1</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://">_sub2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the class sub-menu li tags included in the profile?